# Unable to upload video Tumblr Error - Bad Request (You may only upload one video per post.)

Tags: php, api, video, tumblr

Instead of `video` if I'll upload `photo` with same code its working fine.

```
$post_data = array('type' => 'video', 'caption' => 'hello video','data' => $video_path);
$createPost = $tumblr->createPost($unique_id,$post_data);
```

I'm getting this error while uploading:

> Tumblr\API\RequestException: [400]: Bad Request (You may only upload one video per post.)

Comment: `data` should be string encoded binary contents or supported service URI. Source: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Do you have solved it? If yes, how? I need help too

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in the [official Tumblr API v2 PHP Client](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php). I had created a pull request [here](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/pull/92).
Either take a pull or update your local code to fix your code.